# How to remove repetitve function from angularjs controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-controller, angularjs-resource

Hi i am writing some code staff under angularjs but i has to make duplicated code from controller to other for example let's assume that we have two controllers editProductController and newProductCtrl and we have to call save method my coding style will be like that :

```
var editProductController = function($scope , product){ 
$scope.product = product; 
....
$scope.save = function(){
 product.$save().then(onSuccess , onError);}
....
function onSuccess(response){
   if(response.error === true){
          $scope.productForm.name.$dirty = true;
          $scoe.productForm.name.$invalid = true; 
          $scope.productForm.name.$error.server = response.errors.name;
          ......}
} 
function onError(error){
....
}};
```

and for the newProductController

```
var newProductController = function($scope , Product){ 
$scope.product = {id : null , version :1, ...}; 
....
$scope.save = function(){
 _.extend($scope.product , new Product());
 product.$save().then(onSuccess , onError);}
....
function onSuccess(response){
  if(response.error === true){
          $scope.productForm.name.$dirty = true;
          $scoe.productForm.name.$invalid = true; 
          $scope.productForm.name.$error.server = response.errors.name;
          ......}
} 
function onError(error){
....
}};
```

when the "Product" is an angularjs resource service. so my question will be how can i make better coding style to remove duplicated code?

Answer (score 0):

The best practive would be to include the repeated functionality in an angular service or factory. There's different ways and coding styles to do it. See the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services)

Here's an example

```
app.service('Product', [function(){
    return {aProductMethod: ... , anotherProductMethod: ...};
}]);
```

and then inject the services in your controllers.

Comment: Ideally most of your business logic should be in services. I like to think of controllers as just the "glue" between your logic and your views.

Comment: sorry i have updated my question to be more clear. first i think the same way like you do it but in my case i have to deal with the $scope in onSucces and onError method how can i handle this approch in the service side

Comment: Yes i see, you can't access $scope inside a service so you have to find a way to separate that logic from the repeated logic that you'll put in your  service.

Comment: In your case, I would suggest putting the $http promise in a service, call that promise from your controller and assign the error/success callbacks in your ctrl. But there's more than one way to do it for sure.

Comment: yes, but my case i use angular $ressource service so what i make is calling the resource service and passing the onSucces and onError but the problem persist because i has to handle $scope insidemy controller so i have asked about better way to do this :)

Comment: I think I've also have a similar problem and my other was to use one controller for both forms (e.g. `ProductFormCtrl`) since an edit/create form is oftentimes very similar, the only thing that really changes is the "submit" function.

Comment: but if you want that the edit and new form to evolve independently, what I can do for that?

Comment: make a child controller for each

Comment: thank you good idea, but can i am going to try something like that, i will make a service and passe $scope like a params.